# displaying differents classes using jquery cookies

Tags: jquery, css, cookies, navigation

I'm trying to set different backgrounds and color-fonts customization when the user click on some li links. It worked fine but the colors didn't stay when the pages changed, so i decided to use the Jquery.cookies plugin.
It is working now but formers cookies still appears on formers pages and I can't succeed to set one cookie on all the navigation.
I searched for a long time but I can't succeed to apply anything on my own code to make it work.
I'm pretty new to coding ( and to speak english :) )
so be nice please !
Here is it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("*").addClass($.cookie("bgColor"));

 $('li.blanc a').click(function(){ 
   $("*").addClass("selected-blanc").removeClass("selected-gris","selected-noir");
   $.cookie("bgColor", "selected-blanc");
        });

 $('li.gris a').click(function(){   
   $("*").addClass("selected-gris").removeClass("selected-blanc","selected-noir");
   $.cookie("bgColor", "selected-gris");
        });

 $('li.noir a').click(function(){     
   $("*").addClass("selected-noir").removeClass("selected-blanc","selected-gris");
   $.cookie("bgColor", "selected-noir");
        });
});
```

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Proper syntax to remove multiple classes using [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Use `.removeClass("class1 class2")` instead of `.removeClass("class1,class2")`

In your code, use

`.removeClass("selected-gris selected-noir") // correct`

instead of 
`.removeClass("selected-gris","selected-noir") // wrong`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very quick answer, and for the correct syntax. Unfortunately it still does not work. I added a console.log to show the cookie "bg color" and sometimes it's "selected-blanc", sometimes "selected-noir", etc when I change pages, depending on where I created the cookie.

Comment: @tardif - set up a reproducible jsfiddle.net example for what you're trying to achieve.. by looking at your code it doesn't look like you have any other errors.

Comment: I wonder if it will work with js fiddle because it's basically a navigation problem... Thanks for the advices anyway